# Draw a star using imagefilledpolygon (with diagram)

Tags: php, geometry, gd

Is there a way with PHP GD to draw a star using [`imagefilledpolygon`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilledpolygon.php)?

Where would the points be plotted?

I believe it involves sine and cosine because...

[image]

How can I relate those points to the *center* using **[sine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sin.php)** and **[cosine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.cos.php)** in GD?

Comment: Where would the points be plotted? - it is actually a math question. Did you happen to study it in the school?

Comment: Yes what I actually want to know is the math equation...

Comment: Nice example here http://www.riccardostecca.net/1/?p=37

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes. I suggest you read that manual entry you yourself supplied, as it tells you exactly what you need to do.  It even gives an example of a 3-point star, and there's even an example in the user notes of a 5-sided star.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to calculate the points you need:

```
<?php
function drawStar($img,$x,$y,$radius,$sides,$color,$spikness=0.5)
{
$point =array();
$t = 0;
for($a = 0;$a <= 360;$a += 360/($sides*2))
{
$t++;
if($t % 2 == 0)
{
$point[] = $x + ($radius * $spikness) * cos(deg2rad($a));
$point[] = $y + ($radius * $spikness) * sin(deg2rad($a));
}else{
$point[] = $x + $radius * cos(deg2rad($a));
$point[] = $y + $radius * sin(deg2rad($a));
}
}
return imagefilledpolygon($img,$point,$sides*2,$color);
}
?>
```

Comment: missing rotation argument

Answer (score 0):

Before drawing shape, add DG Liabrary in php.in file.
Here is the code:

```
<?php
   // Create a 200 x 200 image
   $canvas = imageCreateTrueColor(800, 800);

   // Allocate colors
   $pink = imageColorAllocate($canvas, 255, 105, 180);
   $white = imageColorAllocate($canvas, 255, 255, 255);
   $green = imageColorAllocate($canvas, 132, 135, 28);

   imageLine($canvas, 40, 50, 130, 150, $white);        //draw a line
   imagerectangle($canvas, 150, 50, 250, 150, $pink);   //draw a rectange 
   filled with color
   imageFilledRectangle($canvas, 300, 50, 500, 150, $green);//draw a rectangle
   imageellipse($canvas, 600, 100, 100, 100, $green);   //draw a circle
   $points = array (   76,  228,    // Point 1 (x, y)
                105, 228,   // Point 2 (x, y)
                117, 197,   // Point 3 (x, y)
                129, 228,   // Point 4 (x, y)
                156, 228,   // Point 5 (x, y)
                135, 246,   // Point 6 (x, y)
                149, 285,   // Point 7 (x, y)
                117, 260,   // Point 8 (x, y)
                82, 288,    // Point 9 (x, y)
                98, 245     // Point 10 (x, y)
            );
   imagefilledpolygon( $canvas, $points, 10, $white );//draw a star with polygon()


   // Output and free from memory
   header('Content-Type: image/png');

  imagepng($canvas);
  imagedestroy($canvas);
?>
```